# Writing regular expression to retrieve config from webpack config file

Tags: regex, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, regular-language, jenkins-groovy

My webpack.config.js file has the following configuration:

```
 module:
    {
        loaders:
        [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
            { test: /\.json$/, loaders: ['json-loader'] },
            { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
            { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject' },
            { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/png' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    }
```

I need to read the loaders section from pipeline groovy script.  I have tried the following regular expression, but it is not working. Could someone help me?

```
def findStr = "(?<=loaders:)(\\[)(.*)(\\])"

File file = new File('C:/Tools/filewrite/webpack.local.config.js')      
def lines = file.readLines();
StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();

lines.each { String lineS ->
            strBuild.append(lineS)
          }

  def webpackContent = strBuild.toString();



Pattern p = Pattern.compile(findStr);
Matcher m = p.matcher(webpackContent);

while(m.find())
    {
        def str = m.group();
        echo "${str}";
    }
```

**Note:**

> Same program is working perfectly in Eclipse groovy project, but not
>   working in Jenkins pipeline script.

Comment: you may want to tag this with more than just `regex`, the regex shouldn't be too bad but this format looks like you want to somehow use a parser instead.  And perhaps `groovy` supports that?

Comment: How are you using the `findStr` regex?

Comment: Updated my question with the information.

Comment: Is the snippet part of a Jenkins pipeline or a plain groovy script?

Comment: It is part of Jenkins pipeline.